# Virtualbox setClipboard through php call

Tags: php, virtualbox

I have been trying to build a basic interface for my users using the soap calls to create virtual machines as needed while not providing them the access phpvirtualbox would give them.

Everything has been going well so far as I have been able work out any issues by observing the how phpvirtualbox handled requests.  Unfortunately I'm hitting a dead end with setting clipboard mode.  Phpvirtualbox does not implement the option to change it so I was unable to use it as an example.  I have tried my best to set up a basic call to the vbox service wrapper provided, and am at the point I get no errors back from the call, but neither do I see any change.  The same issue occurs when trying to get the clipboard status back, nothing happens.

Here is my simple function to do it:

```
    public function setClipboard($linkID){


        $machine = $this->virtualbox->findMachine($linkID);

        $machine->setClipboardMode('Bidirectional');

        $machine->releaseRemote();


    }
```

I have the connections made in the constructor that this function is contained in, and have successfully change power states and cloned/deleted vms, but this is one issue I cannot resolve.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks.